# Does ng-if bypass the logic in its children while ng-show does not, and therefore use ng-if when you know those items will never be shown?

Tags: angularjs

It might be related to this question: [When to favor ng-if vs. ng-show/ng-hide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide)

But I don't find a direct answer -- that is, if `ng-if` evaluates to false, and there are a lot of logic under the children, such as other `ng-show`, `ng-repeat`, etc, then will `ng-if` just skip all those logic?

On the other hand, `ng-show` or `ng-hide` will actually run all those logic, create all the proper DOM elements, but just use CSS's mechanism of `display: none` to hide or show it?  In other words, it could run potentially slow.

So if that's the case, if given a choice between `ng-if` and `ng-show`, if we know the elements (and all its children) won't need to be shown no matter what -- that is, it won't need to be shown by some flags or some toggle in the controller (but a flag in the database tells us not to show this item or section) -- then we may as well use `ng-if` to skip all potential processing?

Answer (score 0):

Correct.

If the expression in `ng-if` evaluates to `false`, child directives, controllers etc will not be initialized/process because they are not yet added to the DOM. `ng-show` on the other hand just hides the presentation, the elements exist on the DOM and associated controller/directive functions will be process like a normal `$digest`.

Also, if the expression *does* evaluate from `true`, child directive linking functions and controllers will be processed. If the expression alternates between `true` and `false`, `$destroy` events will be fired when false giving you an opportunity to clean up your directives, controllers, $scopes etc, and linking/controller functions will be processed again once `true`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21410877/670151) here gives an example showing the order of ops for digestion which will happen once if is true.